# Find a specific line of a text file (not by line_number) and store it as a new String

Tags: java, arrays, text-files

I am trying to read a text file in java using FileReader and BufferedReader classes. Following an online tutorial I made two classes, one called ReadFile and one FileData. 
Then I tried to extract a small part of the text file (i.e. between lines "ENTITIES" and "ENDSEC"). Finally l would like to tell the program to find a specific line between the above-mentioned and store it as an Xvalue, which I could use later. 
I am really struggling to figure out how to do the last part...any help would be very much apprciated!

//FileData Class

```
    package textfiles;

    import java.io.IOException; 


    public class FileData {

public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {

    String file_name = "C:/Point.txt";

    try {

        ReadFile file = new ReadFile (file_name);
        String[] aryLines = file.OpenFile();

        int i;
        for ( i=0; i < aryLines.length; i++ ) {
        System.out.println( aryLines[ i ] ) ;
}

    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage() );
    }

 }

 }
```

// ReadFile Class

```
    package textfiles;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.lang.String;

    public class ReadFile {

private String path;

public ReadFile (String file_path) {
    path = file_path;
}

public String[] OpenFile() throws IOException {

    FileReader fr = new FileReader (path);
    BufferedReader textReader = new BufferedReader (fr); 

     int numberOfLines = readLines();
      String[] textData = new String[numberOfLines];
     String nextline = "";

     int i;
             // String Xvalue; 

    for (i=0; i < numberOfLines; i++) {
         String oneline = textReader.readLine();

         int j = 0;

         if (oneline.equals("ENTITIES")) {
             nextline = oneline;
             System.out.println(oneline);
             while (!nextline.equals("ENDSEC")) {
                 nextline = textReader.readLine();
                 textData[j] = nextline;

            //  xvalue = ..........

                 j = j + 1;
                 i = i+1;
             }
         }       
         //textData[i] = textReader.readLine();
     }

     textReader.close( );
     return textData;

}

int readLines() throws IOException {

    FileReader file_to_read = new FileReader (path);
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader (file_to_read);

    String aLine;
    int numberOfLines = 0;

    while (( aLine = bf.readLine()) != null ) {
        numberOfLines ++;
    }

    bf.close ();

    return numberOfLines;

}

}
```

Comment: Providing an example of the text file would help others visualize your problem.

Comment: What specific line between the two you mentioned do you want to store?

Comment: Are you only interested in the specific line you store in the xValue variable? WHat distinguishes this line among the other ones?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what line you are specifically looking for but here are a few methods you might want to use to do such operation:

```
private static String START_LINE = "ENTITIES";
private static String END_LINE = "ENDSEC";

public static List<String> getSpecificLines(Srting filename) throws IOException{
    List<String> specificLines = new LinkedList<String>();
    Scanner sc = null;
    try {
        boolean foundStartLine = false;
        boolean foundEndLine = false;
        sc = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename)));
        while (!foundEndLine && sc.hasNext()) {
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            foundStartLine = foundStartLine || line.equals(START_LINE);
            foundEndLine = foundEndLine || line.equals(END_LINE);
            if(foundStartLine && !foundEndLine){
                specificLines.add(line);
            }
        }
    } finally {
        if (sc != null) {
            sc.close();
        }
    }
    return specificLines;
}

public static String getSpecificLine(List<String> specificLines){
    for(String line : specificLines){
        if(isSpecific(line)){
            return line;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public static boolean isSpecific(String line){
    // What makes the String special??
}
```

Comment: I am working on dxf file (ascii format) which I am reading as a text file. What is so special about these lines is that they are always followed by coordinates. So, by identifying these lines   , I can then store the coordinates as a new String and import them later into a database (or so I hope :-0).

Answer (score 0):

When I get it right you want to store every line between *ENTITIES* and *ENDSEC*?

If yes you could simply define a **StringBuffer** and append everything which is in between these to keywords.

```
// This could you would put outside the while loop
StringBuffer xValues = new StringBuffer();

// This would be in the while loop and you append all the lines in the buffer
xValues.append(nextline);
```

If you want to store more specific data in between these to keywords then you probably need to work with **Regular Expressions** and get out the data you need and put it into a designed DataStructure (A class you've defined by our own).

And btw. I think you could read the file much easier with the following code:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new
InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(filename)));

try {
   while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
     if(line.equals("ENTITIES") {
       ...
     }

} (IOException e) {
   System.out.println("IO Exception. Couldn't Read the file!");
}
```

Then you don't have to read first how many lines the file has. You just start reading till the end :).

**EDIT:**

I still don't know if I understand that right. So if *ENTITIES POINT 10 1333.888 20 333.5555 ENDSEC* is one line then you could work with the **split(" ")** Method.

Let me explain with an example:

```
String line = "";
String[] parts = line.split(" ");
float xValue = parts[2]; // would store 10
float yValue = parts[3]; // would store 1333.888
float zValue = parts[4]; // would store 20
float ...    = parts[5]; // would store 333.5555
```

**EDIT2:**

Or is every point (x, y, ..) on another line?!

So the file content is like that:

```
ENTITIES POINT 
10 
1333.888 // <-- you want this one as xValue 
20 
333.5555 // <-- and this one as yvalue?
ENDSEC

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new
InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(filename)));

try {
   while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
     if(line.equals("ENTITIES") {

        // read next line
        line = reader.readLine();
        if(line.equals("10") {
         // read next line to get the value
         line = reader.readLine(); // read next line to get the value
         float xValue = Float.parseFloat(line);
        }

        line = reader.readLine();

        if(line.equals("20") {
           // read next line to get the value
           line = reader.readLine(); 
           float yValue = Float.parseFloaT(line);
        }
     }

} (IOException e) {
   System.out.println("IO Exception. Couldn't Read the file!");
}
```

If you have several ENTITIES in the file you need to create a class which stores the xValue, yValue or you could use the **Point** class. Then you would create an ArrayList of these Points and just append them..

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I am trying to find a specific line (with a given name) tell the program to store the exactly following line. So if for example I have:                                                ENTITIES
POINT
 10
1333.888
 20
333.5555
ENDSEC     (as a column)                                                              I need to tell the program, whenever you find " 10" line, store next line as the Xvalue, and whenever you find " 20" line, store next line as Yvalue. I hope this makes sense. Thank you once again.

Comment: My mistake, I am sorry! It is not all in one line, the text file is written out as a column, so each line only holds one word or value. So when the line " 10" (and by "10" I don't mean the number of the line, but what this line holds, it could "MYNAME" for example) is met, I need to store, the next line, which holds the actual coordinates. I am sorry for my bad description.

Comment: Okay, check my other version. There I think I made it the way you want it ;) and I see that you're new here. Just to let you know if you're happy with an answer you can upvote the answer and if the answer has brought you to the solution you can accept the answer as correct answer..

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort! I am really close to getting the solution now! I am trying to paste your code in a new class  and although I am getting an unexpected error in the "main method" I am sure it's easy to fix.